# Get Bastion Shareable Link REST api results into an error

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

We have provisioned few Azure VMs and have also provisioned the Azure Bastion resource within the same Azure VNET (inside its own dedicated subnet) as that of VMs, the entire set up appear to work fine as we can establish the RDP and SSH sessions using bastion, however the [REST endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/getbastionshareablelink/getbastionshareablelink) to get the bastion shareable links does not appear to work and always comes back with an error below

> *No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://{bastionregion}.network.azure.com:30018/xxxxxxx-ca3c-xxxx-ae7c-xxxxxxxxxx/132229390607747023/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{bastion-rg}/providers/Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts/{bastion-host-name}/getShareableLinks?api-version=2019-11-01'*

It also appears that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/getbastionshareablelink/getbastionshareablelink)'s 'Try It' also results into the same error. 
Has anyone else tried it or have ever managed to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the doc that you've shared, the call should be to the management endpoint - 
`https://management.azure.com`.

Also, since there is no public documentation for this, I believe this feature is still a work-in-progress. Anyhow, let me confirm with the respective backend team and will update you on this.

**Update:**
This is still only in private preview and not GA.We are working on opening the API to everyone. We will however not be providing official support for this at this time. We will reassess providing support at a future time.

Comment: Finally the shareable links of Azure bastion has reached the GA - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/generally-available-azure-bastion-shareable-links/